# Convert the last column of a data frame from hex to decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that I want to filter. I would like to convert the values in the last column from hex to decimal. Is there a way to do it without specifying the name of the column because name may change over time for this document. See examples below.

Input:

| Name | Class | Color | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | G3 | Pink | 0002 |
| Jos | G2 | Green | 000A |
| Pam | G5 | Blue | 000F |

Output:

| Name | Class | Color | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | G3 | Pink | 2 |
| Jos | G2 | Green | 10 |
| Pam | G5 | Blue | 15 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.columns[-1]] = df[df.columns[-1]].apply(int,base=16)

>>> df
  Name Class  Color  Count
0  Ron    G3   Pink      2
1  Jos    G2  Green     10
2  Pam    G5   Blue     15
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting this error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\n'

Comment: You have a blank string or something else in your column which cannot be cast to an `int`.

Comment: Just realized I was going to the wrong column. I actually want to convert the second to last column. In this case would I change the -1 to -2?

Comment: One more thing. I am also trying to do is remove all the rows where the last column is less than 4. How can I do that, again without specifying the column name?

Comment: `df[df.columns[-2]<=4]`. Btw, please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments. Anything not related to the question heading should be asked a new question. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).