# Filtering rows of pandas data frame by column value without specifying column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter the rows of a data frame where the last column is less than 4, without specifying the column name.
[See this question for context on data frame] ([Convert the last column of a data frame from hex to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68551312/convert-the-last-column-of-a-data-frame-from-hex-to-decimal/68551349?noredirect=1#comment121165994_68551349))

I used the solution provided by @not_speshal but I am getting this error.
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.
How can I fix it?

Comment: The comment given in thee prvioud question is propbably right. You seem to have some string that cannot be changed to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is wrong. When you use this one:

```py
df[df.columns[-2]<=4]
```

What you do is to compare the name of the column at index -2 with 4. Like "Color" > 4, which gives an error.
Try this one:

```py
df[df[df.columns[-2]]<=4]
```